# Interview - show apps in google play / appstore or web platforms with login from former employer

Tags: interviewing

Am I allowed to show apps (not code) in production that I've implemented for former employer in a job interview?

Comment: If they're publicly available the answer is typically yes, but this depends on the company, the client, any NDAs that may be in force etc. For instance, some companies will be happy to take the money to develop an app for a controversial organisation but won't want to associate their name or that of their developers with said organization. Voting to close as company-specific.

Answer (score 4):

If said apps are publicly available and you get them through a public channel (for example you load them on your private tablet through the public store and pay for them with your own money and have your own private user account) and you did not sign anything that would explicitly prevent you from doing so, then yes, that's perfectly fine.

As a guideline, anything *your interviewers* could do themselves is fine. Accessing a public store, downloading an app for example. Anything you need special knowledge or credentials from your former employer is not. Logging in with your employee account for example would be bad.

Comment: In case of apps marketed to companies, where it may be difficult to set it up on your private computer, any publicly available website of your previous employer that the employers could access themselves are also fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just use your practical judgement.

This is a *former* employer who has left you with credentials to login to a public-facing application. Presumably, your credentials can be cut at anytime, so you are taking a risk of not being able to login during the interview show-and-tell.

Assuming the login-risk isn't a problem, any "dial-a-lawyer" will say that NO, it is a bad idea. But in reality, it won't hurt to demo the application as long as you aren't being unethical in doing so. No one gets harmed if you just give a tour of the application, what it does, and all about your role in its development.

The only thing I can imagine that would be an immediate absolute "NO" is if you gave the login credentials to the interviewer.

One thing you might consider is to instead capture a screencast of the application being used and narrate the interaction. This way you're immune from changes, you aren't reliant on logging in during the interview, and you have the option of censoring any sensitive info.